# Debounce operator breaks publisher in Combine

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

Hi guys i have the following data model for registering a user in my app:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine
import SwiftExtensions

class RegisterData {

    @Published var firstName: String = ""
    @Published var middleName: String = ""
    @Published var lastName: String = ""
    @Published var email: String = ""
    @Published var postcode: String = ""
    @Published var termsAggreed: Bool = false
    @Published var receiveNews: Bool = false
}

extension RegisterData: Publisher {

    typealias Output = Bool

    typealias Failure = Never

    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, RegisterData.Failure == S.Failure, RegisterData.Output == S.Input {

        // works only if debounce transform is removed or moved after all combineLatest transforms
        let publisher = $firstName
            .combineLatest($middleName, $lastName) { !$0.isEmpty && !$1.isEmpty && !$2.isEmpty }
            .combineLatest($postcode, $email) { $0 && !$1.isEmpty && $2.isValidEmail }
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: RunLoop.main) // try to debounce only texts, but not working
            .combineLatest($receiveNews, $termsAggreed) { $0 && $1 && $2 }
            .removeDuplicates()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        publisher.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
    }
}
```

I have a view controller with a couple of `UITextField`s and two `UISwitch`es that populates an instance of this `RegisterData` class

I want to 'debounce' only the change of the properties that store Strings because they will be populated by the user from the text fields, but the way i am applying these transformations in `func receive<S>(subscriber:)` to come up with the `Publisher` that i need, makes it so that it does not send any new values. If i comment out the `.debounce` transformation it sends updates. If i put the `.debounce` transformation before `.removeDuplicates()` it sends updates, however it 'debounces' the booleans too.

### How can i achieve debounce only for the `String`s ?

I tried debouncing each one of them individually (lets say one of them holds potential username, that has to be checked on server if it is free, so i want to debounce the API call only on it) but it didn't work

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps your tests with individual debounce didn't work because you haven't declared `RegisterData` as `ObservableObject`?

Answer (score 0):

The question is already old, but in case you didn't find a solution so far, perhaps the following is what you are looking for:

Your strings prefixed with $ are publishers in itself, therefore you can simply "debounce" them by applying the debounce operator on each of them.

Your code would look like the following:

```swift
let publisher = $firstName.debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
    .combineLatest(
        $middleName
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: RunLoop.main),
        $lastName
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: RunLoop.main)) {
                !$0.isEmpty && !$1.isEmpty && !$2.isEmpty
    }
    .combineLatest(
        $postcode
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: RunLoop.main),
        $email
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: RunLoop.main)) {
                $0 && !$1.isEmpty && !$2.isEmpty
    }
    .combineLatest($receiveNews, $termsAggreed) { $0 && $1 && $2 }
    .removeDuplicates()
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

The code duplication is ugly, but perhaps you can make an extension for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i haven't played with Combine in quite some time but soon i will find time to have a play again and check your solution